# Deleting registry entries - what happens

Tags: c#, key, registry

I have a program, which deletes some registry entries, which I searched before. The program searches for registry keys, which referring to a DLL, but this DLL does not any more exist on the computer. In short: They are rubbish and I want to delete them. But what I want to know is this:

The number of registry keys which I found is different than the number of keys, which I delete. 
As an example, in the first search, I found `3880 keys`, and there were `deleted 2230`. I found out, that some keys are written two times. A copy in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and a copy in `HKEY_CLASS_ROOT`. And when I delete only a copy in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, then also a copy in `HKEY_CLASS_ROOT` will be deleted (automatically, without my help, in the background). And in my search I search for keys in both HKEY's.

When this is true, then I could search only in one of HKEY's. So I searched for my keys only in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Now I found `2266 keys` and `deleted 2230`. I made a comparison and found out, that the 36 keys, which were not deleted by me (and also not counted), didn't exist anymore.

So my question is: What happens in the background? My assumptions is, that somes references will be deleted automatically, but is there any rule for it?

Comment: If there is some `automatically deletion` from the OS, than I think it's difficult to say any thing about rules..

Comment: Paste your code,what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is not a hive in itself and is merely a pointer to keys underneath HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER. ergo there is only one key that get deleted. however Windows logically shows these keys as HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for easier access. This is the same with HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG.

The content of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT comes from two sources: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes.

from: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739822(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_CLASS_ROOT is just a shortcut to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.